# What is charge qubit, flux qubit and phase qubit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, superconductivity, quantum-computer

What are the differences among charge qubit, flux qubit and phase qubit?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that each one has its own wikipedia page ...

- [Charge Qubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_qubit)
- [Flux Qubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_qubit)
- [Phase Qubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_qubit)

Now about the concepts they share : they are all some implementation of the [superconducting quantum computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_quantum_computing) scheme and they are all based on the non-linearity of the [Josephson relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect).

Other superconducting Qubit exist, like the [transmon Qubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmon), the [fluxonium](http://qulab.eng.yale.edu/devices.html), and all are representative of the recent interest in [circuit quantum electro-dynamics (circuit-QED)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_quantum_electrodynamics).

Now if you make a longer question you will get a longer answer ... and if you ask a precise question you will get a precise answer ...

Answer (score 0):

From

[https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-20726-7_17#:~:text=Roughly%20speaking%2C%20the%20charge%20qubit,I_%5Cmathrm%7Bb%7D](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-20726-7_17#:%7E:text=Roughly%20speaking%2C%20the%20charge%20qubit,I_%5Cmathrm%7Bb%7D).

> Roughly speaking, the charge qubit is a box for charge, controlled by
> an external voltage Vg; the flux qubit is a loop controlled by an
> external magnetic flux Φext ; and the phase qubit is a Josephson
> junction biased by a current Ib.

(I was able to download the relevant chapter)